# Android NDK - OpenGL ES Tutorial/Libraries

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, libraries

Hey! Im looking for an OpenGL library/framework to handle basic drawing code etc for me. Otherwise im also looking for some NDK and OpenGL ES tutorials, I cant seem to find anything out there!

Any information would be helpful cheers.

Adam

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you have downloaded the NDK from Android site, you must have some sample code:
For eg:, when you unzipped the NDK, you have a sample here:
android-ndk-r4b-windows\android-ndk-r4b\samples\san-angeles

That's a great example for OpenGL ES.

Comment: Currently it is not downloaded by default with the ndk. You will need to download it explicitly: https://developer.android.com/ndk/samples/index.html

Answer (score 4):

The best option is to start with the official Android NDK itself (http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html). It contains a bunch of OpenGL ES demos.

If you find them too simplistic you have to check out open-source rendering frameworks.

I'm one of the developers of open source Linderdaum Engine (http://www.linderdaum.com) project. It contains a portable renderer based on OpenGL 3 and OpenGL ES 2 that runs on Windows, Android and partially MacOS. The demos contains both simple examples and a couple of complete games from Android Market.

Answer (score 3):

Checkout the [NeHe Android Ports](http://insanitydesign.com/wp/projects/nehe-android-ports/). They're in Java, but should help you find your way. And the original [NeHe tutorials](http://nehe.gamedev.net/) are a useful reference too.